# Relative links are displaying the wrong base domain after page redirect

Tags: html, redirect, cname, a-records

I have a free webspace with the address

```
my.freewebhost.com
```

and a domain

```
mydomain.com
```

which redirects to the app directory of said webspace. I can reach my index.html with mydomain.com.

The index.html contains page anchors like this:

```
<a href="#">some content</a>
```

Now when I hover over the anchor, I see

```
my.freewebhost.com/#
```

but I would expect something like this:

```
mydomain.com/#
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: I am terribly confused by this setup.  But I assume you can simply make the a href="http://mydomain.com/#" and make it an absolute path instead

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're using <s>"masked" forwarding rather than 301/302 redirects or a META tag redirect</s> browser forwarding rather than DNS redirection.

If you're using <s>"masked"</s> forwarding, then your page is still being rendered on the original domain (my.freewebhost.com) instead of the desired domain (mydomain.com), which would yield the result you're seeing. But any type of forwarding will still ultimately lead your browser to render the page from "my.freewebhost.com".

**UPDATE:** What you're looking for is a CNAME (or A) record from "mydomain.com" to "my.freewebhost.com", rather than a page redirect at all. It sounds like you're using "masked" forwarding, or else it would be visually obvious that your page is redirecting to the other domain (and from your question it sounds like this is *not* visually obvious in the address bar) ... but the behavior you're looking for should involve a CNAME record (which operates behind-the-scenes at the DNS level) rather than any form of redirect (which affects the browser behavior). Some additional reference: http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-a-cname-records/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<a href="#">some content</a>` to `<a href="mydomain.com/#">some content</a>` and see what happens.

Comment: Worth noting -- while this will achieve the desired visual result, it's simply hiding the root issue, and will need to be {a} applied to all links on the site and {b} changed throughout the site if the domain is ever moved again.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn I think you are correct. Your answer certainly seems like it's getting at the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess files, read into that.

link by: whatever you want to link

and in the .htaccess file you do:

RewriteRule ^/ path/to/file.fileextension [NC,L]